# Angular: node_modules/@types/babel _traverse/index.d.ts(1137,43): error TS1109: Expression expected

Tags: build, angular-cli

I am currently stucked in very weird issue in Angular. I was working on one my branch a week ago it was fine and building correctly. But I don't know how it start complaing during 'ng build' below is the error I am keep getting today:

```
node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(1136,44): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(1137,21): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(1137,37): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(1137,43): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(1139,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

I tried below options to fix this but didn't get any success:

**Option 1** - removing and installing node_modules,
**Option 2** - removing and installing @types/babel_traverse

Can anyone let me know what could be the reason. Here are my local angular/dependancy installed versions:

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.10
Node: 8.15.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.15
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, elements
... forms, http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router, service-worker

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.13.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.13.9
@angular-devkit/core               7.3.10
@angular-devkit/schematics         7.3.10
@angular/cdk                       7.3.7
@angular/cli                       7.3.10
@angular/material                  7.3.7
@angular/material-moment-adapter   7.3.7
@ngtools/json-schema               1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                   7.3.9
@schematics/angular                7.3.10
@schematics/update                 0.13.10
ng-packagr                         4.7.1
rxjs                               6.3.3
typescript                         3.2.1
webpack                            4.29.0
```

Please note that I can't update anything at this point because my project is already in production.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I had to add "@types/babel__traverse": "7.0.13" in my package.json as a temporary solution. But I am still debugging to fix this issue permanently.

Comment: I had the same issue. If you have some update, please update the post.

Comment: I solved this by installing typescript 4.1.2.

Answer (score 21):

Try updating the Typescript to a newer version. Worked for me.

"typescript" - "^3.4.2"

Comment: OP said he cannot do this: "Please note that I can't update anything at this point because my project is already in production."

Comment: This answer works, can be because of a bad version of `typescript`... if you cannot update anything in production, how can you fix the problem....

Comment: The problem went away for me when I updated to the latest: `npm install typescript@latest -D`

Comment: This worked for me, *even though I was already on a version higher than the OP's.* I wonder if it's something about the upgrade process itself...?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and I found a way to bypass the issue but I have to warn, it's a **patch not a fix**. The way to get over this is simple, just download/install an older version of `@types/babel__traverse` following these steps

1. install an older version (I used `7.0.6`) by running the command `npm install @types/babel__traverse@7.0.6`

   - Note: you might want to install that in a separate project or folder so that running a full `npm install` won't overwrite it to the latest version again.
2. then go into that temp lib folder `\node_modules\@types\babel__traverse` and simply copy the `index.d.ts` file
3. then go into the broken project and overwrite the file (`\node_modules\@types\babel__traverse\index.d.ts`)

and voilà it works!!!

#### Edit

As pointed out by @GiffordN in the comments, you could use Yarn `resolutions` or npm `overrides`

```js
// yarn
"resolutions": {
  "@types/babel__traverse": "7.0.6"
}

// npm
"overrides": {
  "@types/babel__traverse": "7.0.6"
}
```

#### Q & A

[Q] So why do we have to do that?

[A] It's very simple, the `index.d.ts` file produced by TypeScript older than `3.5.x` is quite different (its structure is different) compare to newer TypeScript `> 3.5.x`

[Q] Ok but why can't I just add `@types/babel__traverse` to my `package.json` and be done with it?

[A] Because the Babel team decided to use `"@types/babel__traverse": "*"` and that little `*` means **always** download latest version... in other words, Thanks You Babel Team I'm not so happy (sic) to report that you broke my code by being explicit to always use your latest version :( ...and here's the proof, taken from my `yarn.lock` file

```json
"@types/babel__core@^7.1.0":
  version "7.1.10"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types/babel__core/-/babel__core-7.1.10.tgz#ca58fc195dd9734e77e57c6f2df565623636ab40"
  integrity sha512-x8OM8XzITIMyiwl5Vmo2B1cR1S1Ipkyv4mdlbJjMa1lmuKvKY9FrBbEANIaMlnWn5Rf7uO+rC/VgYabNkE17Hw==
  dependencies:
    "@babel/parser" "^7.1.0"
    "@babel/types" "^7.0.0"
    "@types/babel__generator" "*"
    "@types/babel__template" "*"
    "@types/babel__traverse" "*"
```

Take a look at the last line with `*` ­­­­­­↑

#### Final Word

In Conclusion, the **real fix** is to update your TypeScript to version newer than `3.5.x` but if you can't (like me), well then follow the 3 steps I wrote and you'll be back in business.

Comment: This worked for me. In my case, the dependency was **@types/babel-types**. It was compiled with 3.7 typescript version. later I have installed and copied the index.d.ts file which was compiled in 3.5.

Comment: You can instead add `"resolutions": { "@types/babel__traverse": "7.0.6" }` to your package.json to force `"@types/babel__traverse" "*"` to resolve to `"@types/babel__traverse": "7.0.6"` which has the same effect as above but is a fix not a patch.

Comment: Also just a point of clarification @types/* packages are maintained by the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/) org and volunteer contributors, not the Babel Team, and are very receptive to pull requests :)

Answer (score 8):

You can add

```
"resolutions": {
    "@types/babel__traverse": "7.0.6"
}
```

to your `package.json` to force `"@types/babel__traverse": "*"` to resolve to `"@types/babel__traverse": "7.0.6"`.

Methology:

Because `@types/babel__core` dependencies list contains `@types/babel__traverse` with a version set to '`*`' (aka latest) even if you specify a version for `@types/babel__traverse` in `package.json`, `@types/babel__core` will install the latest version of `@types/babel__traverse` in its own dependency chain.

By using `resolutions` we can specify strict restrictions for dependencies of dependencies.

Comment: Very helpful solution and honestly an easy way to resolve this issue!

Comment: This seems like the safest route and it worked for me. "Update ts version" sounds like a shotgun approach.

Answer (score 6):

The different releases of `@types/babel__traverse` and `@types/babel__core` are tagged with the TypeScript versions they support.

Visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/babel__traverse?activeTab=versions and https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/babel__core?activeTab=versions respectively and look at the `tsX.Y` tags listed next to each release, for which TypeScript version it supports.

You need to look these up manually (I don't know how to do this automatically, though it feels like there should be a way) and then configure the compatible versions by hand in `package.json`, e.g.

```
    "typescript": "^3.9.10",
    "@types/babel__core": "7.1.19",
    "@types/babel__traverse": "7.17.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this kind of error due to a dependency update and if you are in production, commit package-lock.json or yarn.lock file.

Comment: Thanks for reply but luckily issue is not in prod right now. But I noticed that third party component which I am using switched their dependency base from npm to yarn. So this might be the reason.

Answer (score -3):

Try installing the latest version of typescript.

```
npm install typescript@latest
```