# TypeScript after 3.1 don't accept callback functions argument types

Tags: typescript, jquery-terminal

I have this issue with [jQuery Terminal](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal). I have quite big d.ts file but it don't work properly I've tried to update dependencies and everything broke. From some time I was not able to update TypeScript because got this type of errors (version after 3.1)

```
./node_modules/.bin/tsc --noEmit --project tsconfig.json
test.ts:18:31 - error TS7006: Parameter 'command' implicitly has an 'any' type.

18 $('.term').terminal([function(command, term) {
```

even that callback function have types defined.

I've checked TypeScript playground and this works fine:

```
type arg = ((x: number) => number) | number;
function hey(list: arg[]) {
  list.forEach(x => {
    if (typeof x === 'function') {
      x(10);
    }
  });
}

hey([10, function(x) { x.toFixed(10); return x }]);
```

I have function without types when I use hey and types is taked from my callback definition. Anybody have a clue why this may happen and how to fix it?
The problem is that when I don't update typescript I've got error from babel_traverse like TypeScript don't typecheck the code at all got thousands of errors from typescript on invalid syntax see: [Angular: node_modules/@types/babel _traverse/index.d.ts(1137,43): error TS1109: Expression expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63903376/387194)

IF you don't know the answer maybe you know how to debug my typescript d.ts file so I can find the problem myself.

**EDIT:**

this is part of the types declaration:

```js
type TypeOrArray<T> = T | T[];
declare namespace JQueryTerminal {
    type interpreterFunction = (this: JQueryTerminal, command: string, term: JQueryTerminal) => any;
    type terminalObjectFunction = (...args: (string | number | RegExp)[]) => (void | TypeOrPromise<echoValue>);
    type Interpreter = string | interpreterFunction | ObjectInterpreter;
    type ObjectInterpreter = {
        [key: string]: ObjectInterpreter | terminalObjectFunction;
    }   
}

interface JQuery<TElement = HTMLElement> {
    terminal(interpreter?: TypeOrArray<JQueryTerminal.Interpreter>, options?: TerminalOptions): JQueryTerminal;
}
```

The problem is that this worked fine in previous version of TypeScript.

and here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "strict": true,
        "lib": ["es2015", "ES2018.Promise", "dom"]
    },
    "exclude": ["npm"]
}
```

and I have this in test.ts that check the types in CI:

```
/// <reference path="./js/jquery.terminal.d.ts" />

import "jquery";
import "jquery.terminal";


function test_type<T>(x: T) {};

// this works
$('.term').terminal(function(command, term) {
    term.echo(command);
});
// this also works
$('.term').terminal(function(command) {
    this.echo(command);
});
// this doesn't work, function in array
$('.term').terminal([function(command, term) {
    term.echo(command);
    return Promise.resolve(document.createElement('div'));
}]);
```

Comment: how is `command` typed then? can you share the relevant part of your `d.ts` file?

Comment: @thedude added relevant types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `TypeOrArray` with explicit function overloads seems to fix this issue:

```
interface JQuery<TElement = HTMLElement> {
   terminal(interpreter?: JQueryTerminal.Interpreter): any;
   terminal(interpreter?: JQueryTerminal.Interpreter[]): any;
}
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEHkBOBBJSCGIA8MB8UAvLANoC6UAPrANwBQdAJhAMYA2GS0AdhgLYQAzmAwtoAKQCKAVwhIQMOXwCWvNlADedKDqihIUVcDlguxpADFp3FsGUB7bkSgAKYAAtlggFxQM3EAAaKBZ7Pj5-Rl9BYCRVAHNg8z5ffxAASiICNPpdPXg9JVUMNgQAIwArVmArGztHZxcAOhbOeJ9XGLjueKoobmk+Mrk+gCUIeIBRAA8wdPJMwgIAN3tlRlzdfWgASW5zUwhzZy6EvqMTMzla2wcnanKq2z2Dq6RNnW2oR+qXy6ORsQtHk8iQANYQEDRWIJMi+H7Pfb-Y7UZLFUqVao3ercD5QAC+ujo+IYFyQADNRBIZHIcDBJmwIAJ9s4ABIwACyABkGUyIPsCMCtkU1C4yYdzAB+XxSWTyRRIFRqJp-JASuTpVIBPFo0Xit7SqCy2kKpUlFVItVvBZakD0EmhbgxPzODSEjCCI00+QMDBNXUlFwkcnWW6OFyhcKRJJKTJCnRmaRIJyxWTEsjpX3+kWBkN1O4RsIRbiMGOKuPaXSJ5N6JBp-GZoA)

Comment: I'm not sure why but it don't work in my project, I've changed to code, also tried to use local file for jQuery Terminal and my typescript test fail to run with same errors.