# ERROR in node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(68,50): error TS1005: ']' expected

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I'm updating angular 5 to 6V.

I followed all the steps in the guide - https://update.angular.io/?v=5.2-6.0

```
ng version
Angular CLI: 6.2.9
Node: 14.15.5
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.1.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.8.9
@angular/cdk                      5.2.5
@angular/cli                      6.2.9
@angular/material                 5.2.5
@angular/platform-server          5.2.10
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.8.9
@schematics/update                0.8.9
rxjs                              6.0.0
typescript                        2.9.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

now when im running  `ng serve`  I'm getting a large error msg regarding my @type

example:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(68,50): error TS1005: ']' expected.
node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(68,53): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(68,58): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(68,70): error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.
node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(68,83): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(68,84): error TS1128: Declaration or st
```

In my research, I saw that I have to update Typescript to a newer version,
when updating to the latest im getting an error saying I must use typescript@">=2.7.2 <2.10" (now im using `"typescript": "^2.9.2",` )
I ran this command but it still returns the same error.
Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

npm i typescript@2.8.1

solved the issue

Comment: In my case also issue with the `typescript` version,
I just updated the `typescript` version to the latest (4.9.5) and the issue got resolved

Answer (score 17):

"ts-node": "^10.8.1", "typescript": "^4.6.3" finally worked for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just install "typescript": "^4.6.3" worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

Less offensive approach is to add babel dependencies to your package.json file:

```
"typescript": "3.8.3",
"@types/babel__core": "7.1.18",
"@types/babel__traverse": "7.14.2",
```

After this run `npm install`

You can match babel version to typescript by information included in their package repositories (check column named 'Tag').

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/babel__traverse?activeTab=versions

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/babel__core?activeTab=versions

*In my case babel version was overridden by newest because of installation of other package that depend on it.*

Solution author:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74824145/9950085

Comment: i did `yarn add @types/babel__traverse@7.17.1` and `yarn add @types/babel__core@7.1.19` to my typescript `3.9.10`. But the error is still there.

Comment: Try to reinstall your node_modules npm install. I got also package.lock.json which I sometimes delete before npm install. In this file you can also check where babel occurs and define which library override you babel version.

Answer (score 5):

Try updating the Typescript to a newer version. Worked for me.

```
"typescript" - "^3.4.2"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried to do it again, but i am still getting this error: ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=2.7.2 and <2.10.0 but 3.4.2 was found instead.

Comment: I still didn't find a solution. Any idea?

Comment: i updated to ...
    `"ts-node": "^10.8.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"`
and it fixed it.